Why does the Cora dataset split doesn't contain the whole dataset?
I was following this article https://medium.com/@koki_noda/ultimate-guide-to-graph-neural-networks-1-cora-dataset-37338c04fe6f.
In the Train Test Split section they used the following lines to check the number of nodes in the train-val-test split provided by the cora dataset:
print(f'Number of training nodes: {data.train_mask.sum()}')
print(f'Number of validation nodes: {data.val_mask.sum()}')
print(f'Number of test nodes: {data.test_mask.sum()}')

Quoting the article:
"The data was split into 140 training data, 500 validation data, and 1000 test data. However, the total of these does not add up to 2708 cases."
Does anyone know why they didn't use the entire dataset? I checked and there aren't missing labels for the rest of the nodes.
